# Cannot compare date in SQL statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using Joshcam's PHP Mysqli Database Class (github) and have been fighting over comparing dates for a long while now.
Bottom line is could anyone explain this error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Problem preparing query (SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE business_id = 5 AND active = 1 AND date_visit > `2015-01-01 05:02:14` ORDER BY date_appt DESC) Unknown column '2015-01-01 05:02:14' in 'where clause'
```

My query goes:

```
$jobs = $db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE business_id = $business_id AND active = 1 AND date_visit > `".$search_from."` ORDER BY date_appt DESC");
```

Why would my date input be considered a column instead of a field value?

I've tried double quotes, single quotes, no quotes, and it's either turning the quotes to ' or put off by the space between Y-m-d and H:i:s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was mainly that this class doesn't allow for

```
WHERE the_date > $date1
AND the_date < $date2
```

I actually had to use between to solve it. 
My final code:

```
$params = array($business_id,1,$search_from,$search_to,$limit_end);
$jobs = $db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE business_id = ? AND active = ? AND date_visit BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY date_appt DESC, id DESC LIMIT ?",$params,false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using backticks for query variable rather single quote so try to remove backticks from value(`$search_from`) else it will be treat as column

```
$jobs = $db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE business_id = '$business_id' AND active = 1 AND date_visit > '$search_from' ORDER BY date_appt DESC");
```

Comment: I'd tried that before, here is the error I get:
`PHP Fatal error:  Problem preparing query (SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE business_id = 5 AND active = 1 AND date_visit > &#39;2014-12-01 05:11:26&#39; ORDER BY date_appt DESC) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '&#39;2014-12-01 05:11:26&#39; ORDER BY date_appt DESC' at line 1 in`

Comment: And without any sort of quotes `PHP Fatal error:  Problem preparing query (SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE business_id = 5 AND active = 1 AND date_visit > 2015-01-01 05:13:21 ORDER BY date_appt DESC) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '05:13:21 ORDER BY date_appt DESC' at line 1 in`

Comment: AND date_visit > '$search_from' ? just a single quote

Comment: Hi Rakesh, publishing at the same time here :) Yes I've tried with `` (my question), with '' (my first comment) and with nothing (my second comment).

Comment: copy my query and use same as

Comment: I have, and posted the result above. It reads the quotes as `&#39;`

Comment: then check your rawQuery() function why it's getting fails

Comment: `&#39;` is the `HTML entity` representation of the apostrophe. We are talking about `PHP` and `MySQL` here. Where comes the `HTML` encoding from?

Comment: Doesn't make sense since it's a purely php script. The `&#39;` appears as such in the error log. I'm really leaning towards a but in the PHP MySQLi Database Class.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the [names of database objects](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) (databases, tables, fields, indexes, triggers a.s.o.) in backquotes (``` `` ```). This is usually not needed but it is useful (read "required") when the name is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html).

Enclose the [string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) in apostrophes (`'2015-01-01 05:02:14'`) or quotes (`"2015-01-01 05:02:14"`):

```
SELECT *
FROM `jobs`
WHERE `business_id` = 5
  AND `active` = 1
  AND `date_visit` > '2015-01-01 05:02:14'
ORDER BY `date_appt` DESC
```

None of the field names in the query above is a MySQL keyword, there is no need to enclose them in backquotes. I only did it for explanatory purposes.

Your `PHP` code should read:

```
$jobs = $db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE business_id = $business_id AND active = 1 AND date_visit > '".$search_from."' ORDER BY date_appt DESC");
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working for me. Still exactly the same set of errors as in my comments below.

Comment: Double check the quotes. There is no room for "it's not working for me" here.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :) Ok it's not working. It's reading the double quotes as `&#39;`. If I remove the quotes it is offset by the space between Y-m-d and H:i:s. The only way I can get rid of the error if by doing:

`$jobs = $db->rawQuery('SELECT * FROM `jobs`
  WHERE `business_id` = '.$business_id.'
  AND `active` = 1 
  AND DATE(date_visit) >= '.$search_from .'
  AND DATE(date_visit) <= '.$search_to .'
  ORDER BY `date_appt` DESC');`

i.e. casting the datetime as a simple date, and adapting $search_from to just 'Y-m-d'. However although it's error free, it doesn't return the correct results

Comment: Read the part with "there is no room for" as: this is how MySQL works. Don't take it personally. :-)

Comment: Hmm... maybe you just found a bug in the class you are using for MySQL queries...

Comment: Or maybe it's a bug in the version of PHP you are using. The call to `$db->rawQuery()` applies [`filter_var($query, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES)`](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php#L199) to your query. This seems correct. Write a simple script that does only `echo(filter_var('abc\'def"ghi', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES));` and check its result.

Comment: Try to pass `FALSE` as the third parameter to `$db->rawQuery()` and see if it works. Use `NULL` for the second parameter. Stick with the version of the query that encloses the date in apostrophes (the one listed at the end of my answer). Be sure you are using the most recent version of the MySQLi class.

Comment: Are you using a version of `PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class` older than 11 May 2014?